# resolve prototype & jquery conflict with dynamic script loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, jquery

I know that I can use

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
 </script>
```

to resolve the conflict between prototype and jquery after including all jquery and prototype libraries in the head section. However, I am including another .js file in the head section which dynamically loads  a jquery plugin in window.load function. Now I get the conflict. Can someone tell me how to resolve this. Where do I specify the jquery.noConflict()

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's all in the order:

1. load prototype
2. load jquery
3. run `jQuery.noConflict();`
4. load other js file

edit: oops, you need to include prototype first. ([ref](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries))

Comment: I included them in the above order. I get the following error from prototype

(inline !== false ? this : this.toArray())._reverse is not a function

Comment: @ash34: sorry, looks like you need to include prototype first, see the new order.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I specify the
>   jquery.noConflict()

You should put `jQuery.noConflict();` just after the line where jQuery library is included.

Comment: I get the following error from prototype (inline !== false ? this : this.toArray())._reverse is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Load the main jQuery file first of all your .js files.

Then insert the noConflict() - block directly after you load the jQuery library (before any other script files).

Comment: I included them in the above order. I get the following error from prototype (inline !== false ? this : this.toArray())._reverse is not a function